# Issue downloading Twilio Recording in Twilio Rooms

Tags: node.js, twilio, twilio-api

I have some code to download a recording from Twilio

```
getRecordingMedia: function (recordingId) {
    var client = new Twilio(config.twillio.apiKey, config.twillio.apiSecret, { accountSid: config.twillio.accountId });
    var uri = `https://video.twilio.com/v1/Recordings/${recordingId}/Media`;
    var response = client.request({ method: "POST", uri: uri });
    var mediaLocation = JSON.parse(response.body).location;
    request.get(mediaLocation, (err, res, media) => {
        return media;
    });
}
```

I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0

I looked at the response object and its actually a promise.  So, it seems like the documentation is incorrect in the sense that it doesn't handle the promise "then()"

I went ahead and changed the code to use the promise

```
  var response = client.request({ method: "POST", uri: uri }).then((object) => {console.log(object);});
```

And I actually have an error logged

> { statusCode: 405,
>     body: '{"code": 20004, "message": "Method not allowed", "more_info": "https://www.twilio.com/docs/errors/20004", "status": 405}' }

I looked at the documentation on the referred link, but it didn't help me much.

Additionally If I open the url `https://video.twilio.com/v1/Recordings/${recordingId}/Media` in my browser and enter the credentials I get the recording.

So, need help in figuring out if the documentation is incorrect (as to the promise - https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/video/recordings-resource#code-retrieve-a-recording) and why Im getting the error with code 20004.

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The explaination in the error link says it all. You are using the wrong request method.

The documentation says:

> HTTP GET to /Media subresource
>
> HTTP POST
>   Not supported.

Your code says:

```
var response = client.request({ method: "POST", uri: uri });
```

So of course it works in your browser, as browsers make GET requests...

Comment: Thanks, the code samples actually shows as POST, I got it to work using the GET, of course this seems to be a deviation of the code sample as that returns a value of location, its not a redirect.  Doing the GET does a redirect and you need to use the redirect_to value.

Comment: Ah yeah, didn't even look at the code. Not the first time I've seen their examples contradict their documentation. Glad you got it sorted.

Comment: Twilio developer evangelist here. We're always trying to improve our documentation, sorry that this one is broken twice. I'm going to submit a pull request to update this right now.